# Keydown only runs code once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a script that generates a hex code, and changes the background. Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == '32') { 
     var color = "#" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);
      document.write(color);
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;

    }
  });
});
```

The issue is when I press space, it only changes the color once, and I won't be able to press space again to generate another color without reloading the page. [Here's](http://jsbin.com/depoduti/1) a demo. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `document.write`.

it will wipe your script so you should append it in body:

```
$(document.body).append(color);
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

or add a span and set its text:

```
$("span").text(color);
```

[**UPDATED JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/roqosapi/2/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/EVjaH/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').on('keydown',function(e) {
              if (e.which == '32') {

                var color = "#" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);
                $('body').css('background',color);


              }
            }); 

    });
```